# Can Terraform use bash environment variables?

Tags: terraform

When defining the **aws** provider in terraform,

```
provider "aws" {
    access_key = "<AWS_ACCESS_KEY>"
    secret_key = "<AWS_SECRET_KEY>"
    region = "<AWS_REGION>"
}
```

I'd like to be able to just use the, already defined, system variables

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

Is there any way to have the tf files read environment variables?
doing something like,

```
provider "aws" {
    access_key = env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    secret_key = env.AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID
    region = env.AWS_REGION
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, can read environment variables in Terraform. There is a very specific way that this has to be done. You will need to make the environment variable a variable in terraform.

For example I want to pass in a super_secret_variable to terraform. I will need to create a variable for it in my terraform file.

```
variable "super_secret_variable" {
    type = "string
}
```

Then based on convention I will have to prefix my environment variable with *TF_VAR_* like this:

```
TF_VAR_super_secret_variable
```

Then terraform will automatically detect it and use it. Terraform processors variables based on a specific order that order is -var option, -var-file option, environment variable, then default values if defined in your tf file.

Alternative you can pass environment variables in through the CLI to set variables in terraform like so.

```
> terraform apply -var super_secret_variable=$super_secret_variable
```

This doesn't require that you prefix it so if they are something you can't change that may be your best course of action.

You can read more [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#environment-variables) in the docs.

Comment: I'm trying to do this but I'm getting this error: "``The root module input variable "atp_pwd" is not set, and has no default value``. Do I need to put a default value just in case? Or am I doing something wrong? I added a Gitlab CICD variable called ATP_PWD_DEV and then a variable for my job like this: TF_VAR_atp_pwd: ${ATP_PWD_DEV}

Answer (score 3):

You could just use bare provider like so:

`provider "aws" {}`

And make sure env vars available in your shell session:

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="your-key-id"
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="your-secret-key"
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="your-region"
```

Then, check if the above works:

`terraform plan`

If you satisfy the the plan, you might perform `terraform apply` to make the change.

For more details: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/#environment-variables

Comment: While this is true for the AWS credentials it might be worth pointing out that you can pass environment variables to Terraform by prefixing them with `TF_VAR_` as well.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Agreed. While I was trying to answer to this question OP asked specifically about `aws` provider as mentioned in the question description, it would be great mentioning `TF_VAR_` for general use cases that terraform implicitly handle variables even if it's not asked in the first place.