# Input Environment Variables not being read

Tags: terraform, cloud9

I am attempting to use an environment variable in my terraform main.tf file. I ran the following command in my development environment:

```
TF_VAR_source_ami=ami-048e57a7474e7284d
echo $TF_VAR_source_ami
ami-048e57a7474e7284d
```

Here are the contents for main.tf:

```
variable "source_ami" {
  type        = "string"
  description = "AMI to copy this account"
}

data "aws_ami" "ami_to_be_shared" {
  owners      = ["self"]
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "image-id"
    values = ["${var.source_ami}"]
  }
}

output "ami_creation_date" {
  value = "${data.aws_ami.ami_to_be_shared.tags.AMICoreEngDate}"
}
```

When I run `terraform plan`, it prompts me for `var.source_ami` however, when I run `terraform apply -var="source_ami=ami-048
e57a7474e7284d"` it works.

I have also tried declaring the variable without a type and description.

Additional information:

- using AWS Cloud9
- terraform version Terraform v0.11.5
- following this documentation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/variables.html
- Also read the post: [Can Terraform use bash environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330060/can-terraform-use-bash-environment-variables)

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need export the variable.

```
export TF_VAR_source_ami=ami-048e57a7474e7284d
```

or run as one line

```
TF_VAR_source_ami=ami-048e57a7474e7284d terraform plan
```

Take a further read on this [Defining a variable with or without export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export)